# Is that possible to get hyperlink clicked and open in WebView from Label with TextType "Html' in MAUI?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, label, maui

I want to open clicked hyperlink in WebView from Label with TextType "Html" in MAUI. I can't use "Span" just because this text is dynamic and it will have n number of links.
Following is my sample code.

```
<Label Margin="10" x:Name="MyHtmlLabel"
       TextType="Html">
</Label>
```

In Code behind

```
MyHtmlLabel.Text = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\n   <head>\n      <title>Hyperlink Example</title>\n      <base href = \"https://www.tutorialspoint.com/\">\n   </head>\n\t\n   <body>\n      <p>Click any of the following links</p>\n      <a href = \"/html/index.htm\" target = \"_blank\">Opens in New</a> |\n      <a href = \"/html/index.htm\" target = \"_self\">Opens in Self</a> |\n      <a href = \"/html/index.htm\" target = \"_parent\">Opens in Parent</a> |\n      <a href = \"/html/index.htm\" target = \"_top\">Opens in Body</a>\n   </body>\n\n</html>";
```

I can use webview here but it has some issues like - As text is dynamic it is difficult to calculate height of webview for both Android-iOS and display on screen. I have to display other content as well with this webview on screen below this html. I want to display all this html text on screen and want to avoid scroll inside webview.

Comment: Try using TapGestures & bind the command to that TapGesture with the actions to open Webview with those Label text

Comment: Just because text is dynamic it does not mean you cannot use span. I have no idea why you think that making your Labels work like WebViews will be easier job. I would personally parse the text, and dynamically show the controls with bound gestures to them, but I guess inventing the square wheel is also a road you can take.

Comment: @Blu: That won't work in the example shown, because there are **multiple links** within the Label - TapGesture won't know which link was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Although there is an issue for add Gesture on span, [tom-b-iodigital comments](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4734#issuecomment-1290870071) share a workaround. That's add a Gesture on the label, then the span gesture also work. I think that may be helpful to your question.

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Alternatively, click " />
            <Span Text="{Binding Title}"
                  TextColor="Blue"
                  TextDecorations="Underline">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Url}" />
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
            <Span Text=" to view .NET MAUI documentation." />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Don't need anything in TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped event handler for label. And the span gesture also works (Tap command will execute). For dynamic text and links for span, you could use [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/)

==================================

There is a known issue: [Gestures don't work on Label Spans](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4734) which is about not being able to use `GestureRecognizer` on `span`. So you may use Label as an alternative but with some customization to make it act like a span. Consider the following code:

```
public class HyperlinkLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UrlProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Url), typeof(string), typeof(HyperlinkLabel), null);

    public string Url
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UrlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }

    public HyperlinkLabel()
    {
        TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
        TextColor = Colors.Blue;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(async () => await Launcher.OpenAsync(Url))
        });

    }
}
```

When consuming this custom label, probably use `StackLayout`(Vertical or Horizontal), `Grid` or `FlexLayout` (thanks to @ToolmakerSteve comment) to manage the layout. The following is an example for consuming the custom label:

```
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    ...
    <local:HyperlinkLabel Text="{Binding MyText1}"
        Url="{Binding MyUrl1}"
        HorizontalOptions="Start" />
    <local:HyperlinkLabel Text="{Binding MyText2}"
        Url="{Binding MyUrl2}"
        HorizontalOptions="End" />
<HorizontalStackLayout>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: To clarify: This requires breaking the original HTML into pieces, such that the URLs are separate labels. Re layout, FlexLayout is better, if the pieces of text add up to more than one line.

Comment: Hi Liqun Shen, Thanks and appreciate your help here. This solution will not work for me as I have to display link anywhere in the paragraph and text of that paragraph is dynamic. Above html is just an example.

Comment: Hi, @ViralNarshana  there is a workaround to use span gesture. I think use binding and gesture might be helpful to your question. Please have a look.